# Android clear ram on button click

Tags: android, ram

How to clear the ram on button click?

Comment: Search for garbage collection.  But understand why it usually isn't a good idea to do it.

Comment: any relevant code for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
System.gc ();
```

incates to the System that now would be a good time for gc.  Does not guarantee anything though.